# How to convert custome value in excel to date value or text value with PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel sheet where a "custom" field is present with the formula

```
[$-14009]dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

for holding date value. When I import the excel to `mysql`, the value was converted to general value like `41841.203275`. Please give a suggestion how to convert the excel value properly to `mysql` value.

Comment: What do you mean with convert it to a mysql value? Could you please clarify ?

Comment: Means mysql datetime field.

Comment: `[$-14009]dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` isn't a formula, it's a format mask; a formula is something like `=2*3` in the cell

Answer (score 0):

That value is an MS Excel serialized timestamp, the number of days since 1-Jan-1900 (or 1-Jan-1904 if using the Excel Mac calendar).

I don't know how you're reading your spreadsheet, but (taken directly from the PHPExcel Date handling code):

```
public static function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0) {
    if (self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Set self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904

You then have a unix timestamp value that you can use with any of PHP's date functions

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
public static function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0) {
    $dateTime = self::ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}
```